# Javascript Electron Menu() is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am using the `custom-electron-titlebar` module in order to create a customized titlebar. I am trying to change the items in the menu as shown in the documentation:

[image]

However, when i try to mimic the code shown above, it throws me an error while running the app:

Error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Menu is not a constructor
```

Here is my code :

```js
const { customTitlebar, Menu, Titlebar, Color, MenuItem } = require('custom-electron-titlebar');

      titleBar = new Titlebar({
          backgroundColor: Color.fromHex('#282a36'),
          minimizable: false,
          itemBackgroundColor: Color.fromHex('#44475a'),
      })

      const menu = new Menu();
      menu.append(new MenuItem({
          label: 'Item 1',
          submenu: [
              {
                  label: 'Subitem 1',
                  click: () => console.log('Click on subitem 1')
              },
              {
                  type: 'separator'
              }
          ]
      }));

      console.log(menu)

      titleBar.updateMenu(menu)
```

How do I fix this issue? I want to have customised menu-bar instead of the default ones!

Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to import `Menu` and `MenuItem` from the module `custom-electron-titlebar`, but the [package documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-electron-titlebar#update-menu) says one should use `remote.Menu` and `remote.MenuItem`.

The reason why you're getting this exact error message is that in your code, `Menu` is `undefined`, because the package does not provide it. Consequently, trying to use it as a constructor fails.

To use the `remote` module in the renderer process, you'll need to set `enableRemoteModule` when creating the corresponding [`BrowserWindow`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window).

```
const { remote } = require('electron')
const { Menu, MenuItem } = remote
```

If you're working on the menus in the main process, it is easier:

```
const { Menu, MenuItem } = require('electron');
```